# Utilizar Task con conexion a base de datos en C#

Tags: c#, .net, asincronismo

Estoy desarrollando una tarea que básicamente ejecuta un una serie de procedimientos almacenados para cada sucursal que existe en nuestra empresa, para ello utilizo el task que viene en el .net framework 4.0 pero cuando ejecuta 50 veces el procedimiento lanza una excepcion en el catch y es referente a la conexión:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta.

Yo mantengo siempre abierta la conexion la idea es que al terminar de ejecutar todos los Store procedures la conexion se cierre pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, ya que solo ejecuta un aproximado de 50 SP y ocurre el error

Método principal:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("--INICIO DEL PROCESO. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", HORA_INICIAL);

    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine();
    DateTime inicio = DateTime.Now;

    DataSet dsTiendas = getTiendas();
    DataSet dsProcedures = getProcedimientos();
    int sizeT = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows.Count;
    int sizeP = dsProcedures.Tables["Procedure"].Rows.Count;
    int i;
    string serverDb, procedure, tienda = "";
    if (sizeT > 0 && sizeP > 0)
    {
        OpenConnection(true);
        for (i = 0; i < sizeT; i++)
        {
            serverDb = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["SERVERDB"].ToString();
            tienda = dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["U_TIENDA"].ToString() + ": " + dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["NOMBRE"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Incio de Ejecucion de procesos Tienda: " + tienda);
            Console.WriteLine("IP: " + dsTiendas.Tables["Tienda"].Rows[i]["DIRECCIONIP"].ToString());                    
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeP; j++)
            {
                procedure = dsProcedures.Tables["Procedure"].Rows[j]["NOMBRE"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Procedimiento: " + procedure);
                Console.WriteLine("--Inicio del proceso. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);

                Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ejecutarNonQuery("EXEC " + procedure + " '" + serverDb + "'"));

                Console.WriteLine("--Fin del proceso. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);                    
            }  
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Fin de la tarea " + tienda);
        Console.WriteLine("--Hora finalizada. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", HORA_INICIAL);

    }

    CloseConnection(true);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
}
```

Métodos para abrir/cerrar conexión:

```
private static void OpenConnection(bool pMantenerConexionAbierta = false)
{
    InitDB();

    if (!(con.State == ConnectionState.Open))
    {
        con.Open();
        MantenerConexionAbierta = pMantenerConexionAbierta;
    }
}

public static void CloseConnection(bool FinalizarConexionAbierta = false)
{
    if (FinalizarConexionAbierta)
    {
        MantenerConexionAbierta = false;
    }

    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open & !MantenerConexionAbierta)
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Método para ejecutar consultas

```
static public void ejecutarNonQuery(object dbQuerys)
{
    string dbQuery = dbQuerys.ToString();
    //bool respuesta = false;

    if (dbQuery.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = getCommand(dbQuery, false))
    {
        try
        {

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //respuesta = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(dbQuery, ex.ToString(), ex.StackTrace);
            //respuesta = false;
        }
        finally
        {

        }        
    }

    //return respuesta;
}
```

Comment: muy buena pregunta :D

Answer (score 4):

El error se produce porque se está cerrando la conexión antes de que se terminen de ejecutar las tareas asíncronas.

Esto se puede evitar fácilmente guardando las tareas asíncronas en una lista y después usando [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd270695(v=vs.100).aspx) para esperar a que terminen todas antes de cerrar la conexión

El código sería así:

```
// Lista para guardar las tareas de ejecución de consultas
var taskList = new List<Task>(); 

OpenConnection(true);
for (i = 0; i < sizeT; i++)
{
    ...

    for (int j = 0; j < sizeP; j++)
    {
        procedure = dsProcedures.Tables["Procedure"].Rows[j]["NOMBRE"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Procedimiento: " + procedure);
        Console.WriteLine("--Inicio del proceso. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);

        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ejecutarNonQuery("EXEC " + procedure + " '" + serverDb + "'"));

        // Añadir tarea a la lista
        taskList.Add(t);

        Console.WriteLine("--Fin del proceso. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", DateTime.Now);                    
    }  
}
Console.WriteLine("Fin de la tarea " + tienda);
Console.WriteLine("--Hora finalizada. {0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", HORA_INICIAL);

// Esperar a que se ejecuten todas las consultas antes de cerrar la conexión
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

// Cerrar conexión
CloseConnection(true);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30);
```

**Actualización: Control de errores**

Si se produzce un error dentro una de las tareas asíncronas, el resto de tareas asíncronas no se ve afectada. Después, al hacer la llamada a `Task.WaitAll`, se lanzará una excepción de tipo [AggregateException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) que contendrá la lista de excepciones que se han producido

Usando como ejemplo este código:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew((number) => {

        if ((int)number == 4 || (int)number == 6) 
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Error en la tarea: " + number);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ejecutada tarea nº {0}", number);
    }, i);
    taskList.Add(t);
}

try 
{
    Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("**Se han producido errores**");
    ex.InnerExceptions.ToList().ForEach(e => {

        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    });
}
```

El resultado será:

```
Ejecutada tarea nº 1
Ejecutada tarea nº 3
Ejecutada tarea nº 5
Ejecutada tarea nº 7
Ejecutada tarea nº 8
Ejecutada tarea nº 9
Ejecutada tarea nº 10
Ejecutada tarea nº 2
**Se han producido errores**
Error en la tarea: 4
Error en la tarea: 6
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, creo que le hacia falta la propiedad Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray()), eso me funciono, pero tengo una duda, si la tarea encuentra un error por ejemplo que por algún motivo de caracter nose puede ejecutar un insert en una tabla, la tarea deja de procesar todo los demás SP restantes?, pregunto porque corri pero no se ejecuto todo.

Comment: Hola @JoseFelix, he actualizado la respuesta con lo que me preguntabas de los errores. Saludos

Comment: @rsciriano, revisad el mail :D

Comment: Fijate que por algun extraña razon no se ejecuta todos los procedimientos que estan involucrados en la tarea, la ventana se queda activa pero de 10 solo ejecuta 2 y queda colgada la tarea :(

Comment: Hola @JoseFelix, lo más probable es que se estén produciendo bloqueos en la base de datos ¿Que hacen los procedimientos almacenados por dentro? ¿Modifican los mismo registros de base de datos? ¿Que mensajes de error están dando las tareas?

Comment: Como te comentaba estoy consolidado información en un server central, y son mas de 100 sucursales, basicamente estoy insertando toda la información en el server central, son 10 SP por cada sucursal, es decir que tengo que insertar en las mismas tablas para cada sucursal que mando a llamar, el error que me tira es el mismo que el del inicio:
System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requiere una Connection abierta y disponible. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta.

Comment: Hola @JoseFelix en vez de mantener la conexión abierta, podrías usar una conexión independiente para cada tarea, que abres y cierras dentro del método `ejecutarNonQuery` lo de tener una conexión abierta tanto tiempo y compartida por varios threads no es muy buena idea. Saludos